# Only allow two words in variable but allow dash

Tags: javascript

I need to stop the user from entering more than 2 words but allow a word containing a dash to be allowed.

**Allowed**

Mike-David Smith

**Not Allowed**

Mike David Smith

My code is the following which works for only allowing two words but does not recognize a word with a dash as one word

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
var maxWords = 2;
jQuery('#fullname').keypress(function() {
var $this, wordcount;
$this = $(this);
wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
if (wordcount > maxWords) {
    alert("Please enter a maximum of 2 words (forename and surname)");
    return false;
} 
});

jQuery('#fullname').change(function() {
var words = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/);
if (words.length > maxWords) {

    words.splice(maxWords);
    $(this).val('');
   ////////// alert("Please enter a maximum of 2 words (forename and 
surname)");
}
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `"Mike-David Smith".split(/[\s,\.:;]/)`

Comment: What is this for? You know that not all people have two names, right? [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I know that :) but the client have asked for a specific number of words

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes in your regex

- No need to define a word boundary `\b` - since you are splitting, not matching.
- Remove `-` from the set
- `+` instead of `*` to allow consecutive *colons* or *spaces*, etc as one separator

i.e.

```
"Mike-David Smith".split(/[\s,\.:;]+/) //["Mike-David", "Smith"]
```

**Demo**

```js
var regex  = /[\s,\.:;]+/;

console.log("Mike-David Smith".split(regex));
console.log("Mike David Smith".split(regex));
console.log("Mike-David-Smith".split(regex));
```